# Send my own JWT when using social login (ex. google oauth2)

Tags: oauth-2.0, token

I have an authentication server where an user can login (user/password) and it sends back a token so the user can access a private api.

I want to implement social login (e.g. google oauth2) but the redirect flow of these logins prevent me to send back a token.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correct you want pass your custom data (token) to OAuth2 login process. If so you have *state* field in url for it. This field prevented during redirects and sent back to you result page.

Pice of sample code in python

```
state = any_data_base64_coded_or_references
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(....)
next_page = str( flow.step1_get_authorize_url() + '&state=' + state );
```

But be carefull url can ba cutted in 255 bytes. So better pass references to your internal entry